# Is file cached using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript

I'm using `XMLHttpRequest()` to load some js file. Is the file cached by the browser using the following code?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "example.js", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status == 304) {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.text = xhr.responseText;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Why do you need `XMLHttpRequest` for this and not simply create script tag and set it's `src`?

Comment: Asking if file is cached is to vague. Cached on what part? There are numerous types of caching in that kind of communicaton.

Comment: I just want to use normal caching rule, the same as caching static file using `cache-control` @Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal rules for caching apply when you use XMLHttpRequest.

The file may or may not be cached depending on the HTTP headers in the response.